# In Excel/Google Sheets, how can I get the rows between two strings/headings which are in the first column?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a sheet which is formatted like this:

original_sheet

```
Header1
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Header2
Row 6
Row 7
Row 8
Header3
Row
Row
Row
```

I am looking to copy the rows under each header into their own separate tabs, i.e.

Header1_Sheet

```
'original_sheet'!Row 1
'original_sheet'!Row 2
'original_sheet'!Row 3
'original_sheet'!Row 4
```

Header2_Sheet

```
'original_sheet'!Row 6
'original_sheet'!Row 7
'original_sheet'!Row 8
```

Comment: You could do this iteratively in Excel with VBA, or you can do this manually. I would recommend VBA if you're going to be manipulating this data regularly, otherwise, if it's a one-off exercise you'd be better off doing it manually.

Comment: @spikey_richie this is going to be a repeated thing, so VBA it is, which I can handle. Was hoping to avoid that. Thank you.